# How to pass an array of objects through a query string according to REST?

Tags: javascript, angular, rest, url, parameters

#### What is the best practice to pass an array of objects throught query string in REST style?

For example, the array:

```
examples[] = [
  { 
    name: "foo",
    value: "1"
  },
  {
    name: "bar",
    value: "2"
  }
]
```

I thought about it: 
**/items?examples[0][name]=foo&examples[0][value]=1&examples[1}[name]=bar&examples[1][value]=2**
Are there other ways to do this?

Upd:
I need readable URL to show it to the user in the address field. It should display state of some filters in the table, I'm not sending it to the backend.

Comment: That looks like it's a valid format, but it really depends on what your backend expects. Different languages or different body parsers handle query string arrays differently. What are you sending this to?

Comment: @hobberwickey I only use it for frontend (angular) to send users a human readable url with parameters. Then I take the parameters from the url and post to the backend as another object with a lot of other data.

Comment: You could technically JSON.stringify and then urlEncode the whole array and sent as a single var ?

Comment: Your api needs to understand the JSON which you'll be sending as an http post

Comment: [REST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) does not dictate URL formats to that degree.

Comment: @Carl do you mean you're parsing this in javascript? Are you using any library or doing it manually?

Comment: @hobberwickey yes, I'm parsing it in js manually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're parsing this manually in JS, you could keep the structure you have and just write a parsing function

```
var items = {}; 

location.search.split("?")[1].split("&").map((q) => {
  var [token, value] = q.split("="),
      [idx, key] = /\[([0-9+])\]\[(\w+)\]/g.exec(token).slice(1, 3);
  
  if (!items[idx]){
    items[idx] = {};
  } 
  
  items[idx][key] = value;
})
```

This will yield you something with a structure like

```
{
  "0": {
    "key1": "data"
    "key2": "data:
  },
  "1": {
    "key1": "data"
    "key2": "data"
  }
}
```

If you need it to end up an array, it would be pretty easy to convert, but keeping it as an object with numeric strings for keys will prevent an error if it's not sequential.

Also, note there's no error checking or anything here, so if you're going to have query string params that aren't in that format, you'll want to test for that and handle them differently.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't take care about how pass data for a backend, Angular do it for you.

About your example, you probably want to update or save several item. So it's not into the url that you will pass your data but into the Request Body :

```
this.httpService.post(yourUrl, examples, yourHttpOptions).subscribe( (response) => {
  // you manage your response data
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I am not using this url to send data to the backend, it is used to show users a URL with readable parameters so that they can click links and see clear information in the address field
For the backend I am sending these parameters in the request body and this is not a problem

Comment: The case is that I want to display in the address field the state of one of the filters in the table

Answer (score 0):

REST does not care how you encode information into your identifiers.  You can use any scheme you want, so long as it is consistent with the production rules defined by [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#appendix-A).

REST cares a little bit about *how you share information* about creating URI, in the sense that that information should be shared in some readily standardizable form, like an [HTML form](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.3), or a [URI Template](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6570).

We don't, to my knowledge, have a "readily standardizable form" that describes how to transform a json array to a query string.

But... REST does allow code on demand; embedding, for example, a bunch of java script into a resource where that javascript knows how to encode the json into the URI... that *is* in bounds, so long as you have the code on demand itself referenced in a readily standardizable way (like we have with HTML and script tags).

In practice?  urlencode the json representation and put it onto the query string directly.  That will get you through until you start to discover the real requirements that your URI design needs to support (requirements like: operators needing to be able to understand the access logs).